# If $x \not\in \overline{B}$, the set $U-\overline{B}$ is a neighborhood of $x$.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I was solving a problem in topology. Actually my solution is based on the following problem.

Let $A$ and $B$ are subsets of a topological space $X$. Let $x \in \overline{A} -\overline{B}$ and
$U$ be an arbitrary neighborhood of $x$. If $x \not\in  \overline{B}$, the set $U-\overline{B}$ is a neighborhood of $x$.

Actually this is my observation. But I have no idea how prove it.

Comment: $U-\overline{B}=U\cap(X-\overline{B})$, does this help?

Comment: @freakish Thanks for your help. I got it.